# Mocha Test is Passing but Shouldn't be

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

This test should fail as I haven't even got the endpoint up and running yet that my request is trying to call.  But the test runs green.  I'm new to mocha so wondering what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm BDD/TDDing my API.

```
  describe('Then: we receive a successful response', function(){
        it('status code should be 200', function (done){
            let response = yield request.get(url).end();

            expect(response).to.have.status(200);

            done();
        });
    });
```

Comment: I thinks you are doing a async request and expecting before this finish.

Comment: also how exactly are you handling error, in `request.get(...`

Comment: I haven't gotten there yet as in handling the errors.  I'm just trying to get this working

Comment: isn't the fact that I'm using yield that the expect line won't fire off until the yeild line is done?  isn't that the whole thing about yield, instead of using promises yield is cleaner syntax and I think (I could be wrong) the yield waits and then expect is run after the yield line is done?  In other words expect runs after the callbak comes back for the first line that specified yield?

Comment: But (if you are right about the yeild line which I'm not sure you are) it still doesn't answer why this test is passing, shouldn't it fail cause my expect should fail as well as even the first line should fail because there is no endpoint yet!  I'm going to TDD that endpoint out next to get this BDD test to pass

Comment: I assume the expect doesn't run till end() is called on the yield line so I don't think it's an async related issue?

Comment: Doesn't `yield` work only inside [generator functions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-co) `function*()`?

Comment: yes I forgot to put that back in but even after I did Kirill it still had the same result